# How to pass first part of route and then the rest of path nginx

Tags: go, nginx, backend, config

I have an auth_request in my /protected/ path. Everything works fine so far. But I want that every request that includes /protected/ for example /protected/application1 and /protected/application2 will be go first through the /protected/ location with the authentication and if this is passed go to the further location.
I have this so far but it doesn't seem that the authentication has any impact of the route.
So when I call /protected/ everything works as expected, when I call /protected/application1 it doesn't matter if the authentication succeeds or not.

This is part of my config:

```
   location /protected/application1 {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4501;
    }
    location /protected/application2 {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4502;
    }
    location /protected/ {
        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4500;
    }
    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/welcome;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: add `auth_request /auth;` to `/protected/applicationX`

Comment: ok, thank you! So there is no other solution?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/496371/how-to-use-nested-nginx-location-blocks-prefixes-vs-regex-directives